# instantiate game object with children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject(EnemyProducer) that instantiate another GameObject(EnemyFormation) which has several children (actual enemies).

**However, when i instantiate EnemyFormation Gameobject it does not have any children!**

EnemyFormation is a prefab with all the required children.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Here is the EnemyProducer code that Instantiates EnemyFormation:

```
public class EnemyProducer : MonoBehaviour {
    EnemyFormation enemyGroup;
    Transform enemyFormationTransform;
    public float speed;
    float boundary, currentY;
    bool goingDown = true;
    public GameObject enemyFormation;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
       // Create enemyformation
       enemyFormation = Instantiate (enemyFormation);
       enemyFormation.transform.parent = transform;
       enemyGroup = enemyFormation.GetComponent<EnemyFormation>();
       boundary = Camera.main.orthographicSize;
       enemyFormationTransform = enemyFormation.transform;
    }
    void Update () {

        // if all enemies are killed, create a new one
        if (!enemyGroup.hasEnemy ()) {
            enemyFormation = Instantiate (enemyFormation);
            enemyFormation.transform.parent = transform;
            enemyGroup = enemyFormation.GetComponent<EnemyFormation>();
            enemyFormationTransform = enemyGroup.gameObject.transform;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `GameObject  enemyFormation` is your prefab then `enemyFormation = Instantiate (enemyFormation);` overrides it.

Comment: @Krajca that's what i want to do. When the group of enemy is defeated, i want to create a new enemyFormation.

Comment: What Krajca meant is that you store the object you instantiate back into the  variable that holds that prefab.

Comment: I shouldn't do that?

Comment: @Loop You are right, when the bullet collides with the enemy, i destroy the the bullet and the enemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first instantiation may be successful because it cloned the prefab from the Editor but then you reassigned the newly cloned prefab to the `enemyFormation`. When all enemies (children) were destroyed (assume that you were using `Destroy()`) then `enemyFormation` would contain no child. Next time you `Instantiate(enemyFormation)` you were expected to get a `gameObject` without children because it were not the prefab from the Editor anymore (it was reassigned by you).

Sorry I have to delete the previous answer. It is wrong anyway.